# Looking for a programming language for dummies

Tags: c++, lua

I don't know if it is allowed to ask this question here, but I'm going to try any way.

I'm looking for a simple programming language for the average user to understand and write, for in a game I'm making. I'm building my framework in C++.

I was considering Lua, but I think it is probably too hard for the average user.

Only basic actions as walk forward, shoot, grab this, put this here, etc. are needed. It is a tile based game.

Comment: Javascript might be a good choice. It's not a simple language when used fully, but it's quick and easy to learn enough to do simple things...

Comment: How would that kind of script be hard to write in *any* language? It's just a series of actions, which can be expressed one per line.

Comment: True, however I think a lot of users would be scared of the overhead and scary characters needed to program. But yes, making an own interpreter would be an option, however this could get too big..

Comment: Programming is not for dummies. Whatever the language, there are concepts inherent to programming (recursion ?) which are non-trivial.

Comment: How about python? If they just have to say walk, shoot, all they'll have to write will be walk(), shoot(). Python is a breeze to interface to C++ (Boost.Python), so it's better for you in the end.

Comment: @KajToet: It's really not going to get simpler than Lua. Python and Javascript are approximately equal in complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you consider Lua too hard, then you're probably not looking for a generic programming language (another suggestion would be Python). Instead consider creating a [domain-specific language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language). I'll be making some assumptions here about your game, but you could, for example, implement a rule-based scripting language where each script represents an enemy's behaviour:

```
can_see(player) and distance_to(player) > 100:
    run_towards(player)

can_see(player) and distance_to(player) < 100:
    shoot_at(player)

default:
    wander()
```

At each reasoning step the first matching rule could be executed. In that case some form of  [hysteresis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis) will be needed to prevent your NPCs from appearing decisionless.

This basically reduces your programming language to a single if-else-if with a limited amount of keywords and operators to be used. You could even create a custom editor with IntelliSense specifically for your language. If your users are up for it you could have nested rules:

```
can_see(player):
    distance_to(player) > 100:
        run_towards(player)
    default:
        shoot_at(player)
```

At some point you could start allowing variables and user-defined functions, but then a general purpose language might have been a better choice from the start! So you see, the main question is finding a balance between genericity and user-friendliness.

Answer (score 9):

Lua is a fine choice. This is exactly the sort of thing Lua was designed for.

You can greatly influence how easy it is for your users in how you design the Lua API to your game. If you design a convoluted, difficult to use API or require them to use a bunch of the more advanced features in Lua then it will be more difficult. If you instead make an API that's simple to use then it should be easy for people to start from examples and pick up what they need to know.

Answer (score 2):

Just provide a GUI to create the workflow of the game ?

You can have a look at : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_educational_programming_languages those might be simple to understand for a novice

Comment: Guido van Robot seems about right for me, thanks.

Comment: @KajToet: You realize that Guido van Robot is just a GUI tool that writes Python scripts, right? It isn't itself a language.